# New or missing levels in the test set when One Hot Encoding in r

Tags: r, r-caret, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I use `dummyVars` from `caret` when one-hot-encoding. When there is a level in a categorical column in train set that is not in test set or a new level is present in the test set, the resulting shapes of the one-hot-encoded dataframes are different for train and test sets using `dummyVars`. In python when using `OneHotEncoder` from `scikit-learn`, setting `handle_unknown = "ignore"` solves this and results in train and test sets that are the same shape. Is there a package or a way to imitate that behaviour in r? Below is a sample code that showcases the situation of missing or new levels in test set. Using `dummyVars`, resulting train and test sets have different columns.

```r
library(caret)
# Columns for training set
cat.column <- c("cat", "dog", "monkey", "shark", "seal")
num.column <- c(1,2,5,7,9)
class <- c(0,1,0,0,1)

train.set <- data.frame(num.column, cat.column, class)

# Columns for test set
cat.column <- c("cat", "elephant-shrew", "monkey", "monkey", "seal")
num.column <- c(1,11,5,6,8)
class <- c(1,0,1,0,1)

test.set <- data.frame(num.column, cat.column, class)

# OHE train set and test set
train.target <- train.set[class]
test.target <- test.set[classs]
dummy <- dummyVars("class ~.", data = train.set)
train.set.ohe <- data.frame(predict(dummy, newdata = train.set))
test.set.ohe <- data.frame(predict(dummy, newdata = test.set))
```

Comment: I'd recommend doing the dummy creation in the overall data set, not only in the train data set. From a data perspective - if you have a factor variable that would lead to a very sparse dummy that might be "empty" in the test or training data, then you should probably collapse factor levels before doing your analysis.

Comment: @deschen the recommendation to perform dummy creation on the whole data is viable only if you do not plan to actually use the model. What happens if you need to use the model on new data and thus need to account for the possibility that factors in the new data might contain levels not present in the train set.

Comment: @missuse What could be done in that case?

Comment: @moli after dummy creation in test data make sure to remove columns not present in the train data (these will correspond to factor levels not present in train data) additionally make sure to add columns present in train data but not present in test data - their values will be 0 for all rows. Not sure if caret has a way to do this automatically but you can make a custom function. Be sure to order the column names in test data the same way as in train data, some models might not work expected if you don't (particularly xgboost had such a problem several years ago, not sure if it was corrected).

Comment: anyhow caret is outdated, consider switching to tidymodels or mlr3 if you plan to use R for ML.